# Power BI. Creating a graph with user-input parameters

Tags: powerbi, histogram, user-input, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a problem with creating graphs with different parameters. Now I have made histograms of parameters A by choosing Count values of A in the bins, hence, there is a percentage value representing % of a number. But I also need to create the same graph, instead the Count function use the value of another parameter B (I mean, in the axis there will be parameter A, but in the % of values of parameter B.

I know how to create both graphs.

But I also want to add a box, where one can choose what parameter use in "Values" of a histogram - Count of Par. A or with Values of Par B. However, I even don't imagine, how to do it. Could you, please, help me?
Thank you in advance!

I tried to look through options, but still no result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but maybe you are looking for something like
[Let report readers use field parameters to change visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-field-parameters)

If not, add some sample data and a snapshot of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the website. I suppose that I also can create two buttons above the chart to switch between of them. However, in the website it is not explained, how to adapt that above button to switch between graphs. I have already known, how to add them to navigate in the report or add a "blank" one and to tune "Action" to a separate sheet. Could you, please, advise me, how to create these buttons (above) in her report to switch from one graph to another being on the same sheet. Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you create field parameters, a slicer will be automatically added to the report page.